# regex: ignore "!" to diff / merge two files with comments starting with "!"

Tags: regex, merge, fortran, diff

I would like to merge - or at least diff - two Fortran namelist files while ignoring whitespaces. and lines starting with `!`.

I have tried

```
diff -w -u -I '!.*' FILE1 FILE2 
diff -w -u -I '\!.*' FILE1 FILE2
meld FILE1 FILE2
```

but don't have the regex-fu to can't seem to ignore the !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `-I`, `diff` only skips hunks where *every* changed line matches the regex. So, you need to filter out those lines earlier.

Assuming you are using a shell like `bash`, you can use *process substitution*:

```
diff -w -u <(grep -v '^!' FILE1) <(grep -v '^!' FILE2)
```

Note that this may change the reported line numbers and the unified output.

Comment: this isn't working ... even the `grep -v '^!' FILE1` returns lots of lines (commented or not)  perhaps because "!" isn't always at the beginning of the line? but '*!*' doesn't work either. Here is a link to [FILE1](https://gist.github.com/geophtwombly/5105124/raw/3c579b48ee65afa08c213c609ddb82cda6eeb9bf/FILE1.f90)

Comment: If `!` isn't exactly at the beginning of the line, try `[[:space:]]*!`. That will get rid of lines that have spaces (or tabs) before the initial `!`.